# Should I remove 0 when I'm calculating outliers?

Tags: statistics

I'm calculating outliers with two methods:

```
IQR_outlier = ifelse(events > iqr_upper_limit | events < iqr_lower_limit, T, F))
ZScore_outlier = ifelse(z_score < -3 | z_score > 3, T, F))
```

My independent variable is called `events` and it's 0 about half the time.

This distribution looks something like this

```
       n  missing distinct      Mean          .05      .10      .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
  90000        0      85        1.781           0        0        0        0        2        5        9 

lowest :   0   1   2   3   4, highest: 194 209 219 274 301
```

My distribution after I filter out 0-values looks something like this

```
       n  missing distinct     Mean       .05      .10      .25      .50      .75      .90      .95 
   41745        0      84       5.417       1        1        2        3        6       12       18 

lowest :   1   2   3   4   5, highest: 194 209 219 274 301
```

And here is how my IQR and ZScore outlier boundaries change

```
  instance          method upper_limit
  <chr>             <chr>        <dbl>
1 includes 0-values zscore          19
2 includes 0-values iqr              5
```

```
  instance          method upper_limit
  <chr>             <chr>        <dbl>
1 excludes 0-values zscore          31
2 excludes 0-values iqr             12
```

I'm wondering whether it's fair to include 0-values as my outlier calculation. On the one hand, it's part of the data and so it should be included because it counts stuff that matters in the same way as non-0 values. On the other hand, it's weighing down my data because it's such a huge portion and I'm concerned that I'll remove real values that shouldn't count as outliers.

Comment: What makes you think you have outliers rather than rare high values that are part of the distribution?

Comment: I'm looking at the number of time stuff happens over a limited period of time and there are high values that are unreasonably large. It would profoundly surprise me if these high values were representative of a real and substantial slice of my population. I think that's validated by the difference between p95 and highest.

Comment: If you know what "unreasonably" large is, then that can be your criterion for an outlier

Comment: Isn't the point of outlier detection that I don't know the precise number for unreasonably large?

Comment: Should I move this to stats.stackexchange?